# Whats the proper way to publish a webhook from a c# application on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, webhooks

I want to create a webhook from my application to notify other systems about events.  Its a c# application running on an App service in Azure.  I've been doing some research and there's lots of articles out there which explain how to consume webhooks, but very little on how to publish them from your application.

I found this article: https://dev.to/damikun/integrate-webhook-under-net-c-backend-4f7

We could do the same but it feels very manual... I feel like every web hook developer will need to build those things so there has to be a better way.  Is there any nuget package that could do this for us, or is there anything in Azure itself that provides a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a decoupled scenario you could leverage [Azure Event Grid custom topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-topics). In your application you send out Event Grid events and other systems can create a subscription on those topics. Take a look at [these code example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventgrid/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid/samples/Sample1_PublishEventsToTopic.md).

[image]

This way, your application only needs to send out events and does not have to know anything about the subscribers making it a easy to implement process.

Subscribers can take action based on the received events using a mechanism of their choosing.